# Absolute Linux without audio (slackware based distro)

Tags: linux, audio, slackware

I'm testing [absolute linux](http://absolutelinux.org/) on a HP mini 2133 and everything seemed fine until I tried to play music.

The volume is always 0% I've searched the internet and none of the solutions I've tried has given me any results.

It Is the first time I try to use a different system to windows and I do not want to go back.

Help me please

Comment: Perhaps the ALSA mixer has your volume turned down. You can check with the alsamixer command. There's also a service which loads the mixer settings upon boot, so make sure that's running (which depends on the init system used by Absolute Linux).

Comment: In addition, if Absolute Linux is running Pulseaudio, check `pavucontrol`. When you play music, you should see the application and a volume indicator, and you should select the correct audio sink if there are several.

Comment: Thanks I already have audio.
But it is distorted
I followed the indications they gave me and I worked, but the audio is distorted, could they help me?